# First time running but not working from 2nd time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with a javascript function which works first time but not from the 2nd time.The console shows: `Uncaught TypeError: pizza_name is not a function`

### My html is :

```
<div class="pizza_name_div">
    <input type="text" name="pizza_name" id="pizza_name" placeholder="Enter your pizza name as u like. i.e : my-pizza" value=""> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="pizza_name_submit" onclick="pizza_name()">
</div>
```

### And My js

```
function pizza_name() {
  if( pizza_name != "" ) {
     .........
  }else{
    alert( "please enter a name" );
  }
}
```

It shows alert properly for 1st time.But not form 2nd

Comment: its working on system

Comment: You're probably overwriting the function. Show us the code under the `if`.

Comment: A function with the same name as a variable. Why you think this will/should work?

Comment: You function and you variable has the same name? That's not good, change them.

Answer (score 2):

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18250/)
js code:

```
   function pizza_name() {
    var pizzaName=document.getElementById("pizza_name").value;
  if(!pizzaName ) {
   alert("no value");
  }else{
    alert( "please enter a name" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with:

```
function pizza_name() {
  var pizzaName = document.getElementById('pizza_name').value;
  if(pizzaName != "") {
     //.........
  } else {
    alert( "please enter a name" );
  }
}
```

It's very important to not assign any value to a possible `pizza_name` variable inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this too

HTML

```
<div class="pizza_name_div">
    <input type="text" name="pizza_name" id="pizza_name" placeholder="Enter your pizza name as u like. i.e : my-pizza" value=""> 
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="pizza_name_submit" >
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#pizza_name_submit").on("click", function(){
if( $("#pizza_name").val()) {
    alert( $("#pizza_name").val());
  }else{
    alert("enter value");
  }
});
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9rtqt4cj/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-use names, you're probably overwriting your function to be a string instead.

(that's what I'm assuming happens in the code you didn't show since you're trying to test `pizza_name` as a string)

```
function pizza_name() {
    if( pizza_name != "" )
```

You'd be better off naming the function something like `getPizzaName`. Name the function for what it `does`, not what it returns.